# Searching for and loading images at runtime in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am working on a unity application that detects objects and then pulls some more images of them from the web. I already have object detection working but I am confused on how to search for images of the objects online and then loading them into unity during runtime. Could someone help me on this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you need to declare the url tab you need to access

```
public static void OpenURL(string url);
```

Opens the URL specified, subject to the permissions and limitations of your app’s current platform and environment. This is handled in different ways depending on the nature of the URL, and with different security restrictions, depending on the runtime platform.

Then here is the code that will help you access the web page you need

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

```
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        Application.OpenURL("http://unity3d.com/");
    }
}
```

this should bring you to the web page you wish to visit.
Though Unity doesn't natively support displaying a live web page as a part of the game. But there are various assets available in Unity's asset store like which enables the functionality for you. You can get the assets according to your choice from here.

https://assetstore.unity.com

once you load the assets that are in the Resources folder, they can be accessed through Resources.Load().

You can unload resources of an AssetBundle by calling AssetBundle.Unload() or AssetBundle.UnloadAsync(bool). If you pass true for the unloadAllLoadedObjects parameter, both the objects held internally by the AssetBundle and the ones loaded from the AssetBundle using AssetBundle.LoadAsset() will be destroyed and memory used by the bundle will be released.